# JQuery with onreadystatechange

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain why all my JQuery attempts to use this event are not working?

```
function readyStateChanged() {
    alert(document.readyState);
}

document.onreadystatechange = readyStateChanged;            // works 
$(document).on('onreadystatechange', readyStateChanged);    // doesn't work
$(document).bind('onreadystatechange', readyStateChanged);  // doesn't work
$(document).onreadystatechange(readyStateChanged);          // doesn't work
```

Comment: Why? Because 'onreadystatechange' is not a jQuery bindable event.

Comment: Patrick's right.  You are trying to use JavaScript in jQuery. You can use jQuery in JavaScript but not the other way 'round.

Comment: jQuery has it's own collection of Ajax stuff: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: $(document).on('readystatechange', readyStateChanged);

Comment: it actually works with Jquery, you just need to remove the "on" on the event name.

Answer (score 12):

```
function readyStateChanged() {
    alert(document.readyState);
}

$(document).on('readystatechange', readyStateChanged);
```

Comment: `bind` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: That not actually the case, `.on()` is preferred but `.bind` is not (yet) deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score -4):

Because u didn't set your function readyStateChanged as a function or added parameter parentheses.

**option 1**

var readyStateChanged = function() {

**option 2**
$(document).on('onreadystatechange', readyStateChanged());

Personally I would avoid a function name what is (almost) the same as a javaScript native object name, function name etc.

Comment: That is not the problem. See the [documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Look about a third of the way down at the example under the headline "The event handler and its environment". It's the same format as the OP is trying to use.

Comment: Yes you are right, my apologizes. With the first 3 options it's still possible to call the function, but not to alert document.readyState again.

Comment: It is `$(document).on('readystatechange', readyStateChanged);` I think